# Bootstrap comparison of means

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, bootstrap

I want to compare means between two groups using bootstrapping, where the groups are represented as separate columns in a data frame.  The implementation below works, but the bootstrap comparison is a new topic for me, and I want to check if this is the *right* way to do this.

Secondary question - would this be a valid way to compare other parameters, like `sd` or `median`, instead of `mean`?

*Note: the data here is just dummy data I am using to test out my R code. I copied it from something else I was working on just to have something to experiment with.*

```
library(boot)

fun_2samD <- function(data, i){
  d1 <- mean(data[i,1], na.rm=TRUE)
  d2 <- mean(data[i,2], na.rm=TRUE)
  return(d1 - d2)
}

# TEST
# populate sample data for analysis
mydata <- data.frame(
  Group1 = c(6.3, 8.3, 6.6, 0, 8.4, 8.6),
  Group2 = c(8.2, 8.7, 8.6, 7.9, 7.1, 7.6),
  Group3 = c(7.1, 6.4, 6.6, 8, 7.5, 10.3),
  Group4 = c(8, 7.7, 7.3, 0, 9.4, 6.4),
  Group5 = c(8.5, 6.8, 0, 0, 7.3, 9.7),
  Group6 = c(5.9, 7.5, 6.5, 0, 9.8, 7.8),
  Group7 = c(7.6, 5.3, 6.7, 0, 6.6, 7.4),
  Group8 = c(9.5, 5.6, 8.8, 0, 8.6, 8.3),
  Group9 = c(8.5, 7.4, 0, 0, 9.2, 8.6),
  Group10 = c(7.8, 6.9, 8.6, 6.7, 6.8, 6.1)
)

# Replace all zero values with NA
mydata[mydata == 0] <- NA

# compare coloumns 1 and 2
bs_data <- mydata[,1:2]
b <- boot(bs_data, fun_2samD, R=10000)
b

#compare columns 3 and 10
bs_data <- mydata[,c(3,10)]
b <- boot(bs_data, fun_2samD, R=10000)
b
```

Output:

```
ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = bs_data, statistic = fun_2samD, R = 10000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
      original      bias    std. error
t1* -0.3766667 0.002554833   0.5952981

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = bs_data, statistic = fun_2samD, R = 10000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
    original   bias    std. error
t1*      0.5 0.004515   0.8005441
```